# CSS: Align items to center, but ignore wrapped lines

Tags: html, css

I am building a UI in which there is an icon inline with a title. I can align this icon vertically with the text very easy when the text is only 1 line, but the issue is when the text wraps, the icon is vertically aligned with the center of the wrapped text. I'll try to illustrate here.

```
<icon>  Example text   <-- super easy to align

        Example text
<icon>  that is quite  <-- undesired output
        a bit longer

<icon>  Example text
        that is quite  <-- my goal
        a bit longer
```

Currently my markup looks like the following (using Tailwind shorthand here to reduce verbosity):

```html
<div class="flex items-center">
  <img />
  <h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>
```

Is there a reasonable way to pull this off? If I skip the `align-items: center` unfortunately the icon floats towards the top and it doesn't look level with the first line of text.

Edit: Runnable demo: http://esm.codes/#aW1wb3J0IHsgcmVhY3QsIGh0bWwsIGNzcyB9IGZyb20gJ2h0dHBzOi8vdW5wa2cuY29tL3JwbHVzJwoKY29uc3QgcGFyZW50ID0gY3NzYAogIGRpc3BsYXk6IGZsZXg7CiAgYWxpZ24taXRlbXM6IGNlbnRlcjsKYAoKY29uc3QgaW1nID0gY3NzYAogIG1hcmdpbi1yaWdodDogMXJlbTsKYAoKY29uc3QgdGV4dCA9IGNzc2AKICBtYXgtd2lkdGg6IDVyZW07CiAgbWFyZ2luOiAwOwpgCgpjb25zdCBhcHAgPSAoKSA9PiB7CiAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgCiAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSR7cGFyZW50fT4KICAgICAgPGltZyBjbGFzcz0ke2ltZ30gc3JjPSJodHRwczovL3NvdXJjZS51bnNwbGFzaC5jb20vcmFuZG9tIiB3aWR0aD0iMjRweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNHB4IiAvPgogICAgICA8aDEgY2xhc3M9JHt0ZXh0fT5FeGFtcGxlIFRleHQgQmxvY2s8L2gxPgogICAgPC9kaXY+CiAgYAp9CgpyZWFjdC5yZW5kZXIoaHRtbGA8JHthcHB9IC8+YCwgZG9jdW1lbnQuYm9keSk=

Answer (score 1):

Position property will be your best shot. `position: relative`  on the `flex` class then `position: absolute` on the `img`. Then you decide `top, left` on the image. That will help you place them the way you want

Comment: Even simpler than that I can just get total height for a line of text (happens to be 30px), subtract image height (happens to be 24px), and then just split the remainder and add a marginTop with that. I'm sure this is about as hacky & likely to break as it'll get though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `align-items: flex-start` instead and if it does not get aligned, then I would suggest you to look at your text or image margins/paddings.

Comment: `flex-start` won't do anything for vertical centering. There are no margins or padding, images naturally float to the top of the content, text does not.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code sample with a runnable Code Snippet?

Comment: I gave you a complete code sample. That's literally all there is.

Comment: There's now a runnable demo in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [flex auto-margins](https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/); I added the tailwind class `mb-auto` to the images and you can see in the snippet below that they meet your stated requirements:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex items-center mb-3">
  <img class="mb-auto" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png" height="20" width="20" />
  <h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="flex items-center mb-3">
  <img class="mb-auto" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png" height="20" width="20" />
  <h1>Example Text that <br/> is quite a <br/> bit longer</h1>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use [flex's `align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) to a similar effect (`"self-start"` in Tailwind):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex items-center mb-3">
  <img class="self-start" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png" height="20" width="20" />
  <h1>Example Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="flex items-center mb-3">
  <img class="self-start" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png" height="20" width="20" />
  <h1>Example Text that <br/> is quite a <br/> bit longer</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Neither of those work. I've added a demo to the main post, but either way, you're doing things here that alter the parameters.